# Unable to use EL in jsp in Spring MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, el, apache-tiles

I am developing my first spring-Tiles application. When I am tryitg display a table using EL in jsp file. I am getting the following error.

Please Help. Why I am getting error in the below code?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <c:forEach var="listValue" items="${tableView.tableHeaders}">
                <tr>
                    <%
                        for(int i = 0;i<5;i++){
                    %>
                    <td><%=${listValue.get(i)}%></td><!--Here I am getting Error -->
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the below Errors in Eclipse:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
     MethodInvocation
    - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
    - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
```

And

```
Syntax error, insert "}" to complete Block
```

Comment: Scriptlets (i.e. blocks surrounded by `<%` and `%>` must contain Java code. Not JSP EL. And they should be avoided. Use the JSP EL only. Transform your for loop to a c:forEach loop.

Comment: If I use c:forEach how I can iterate through listValues

Comment: Just like you did for the headers: `<c:forEach var="element" items="${listValue}">` (I'm assuming listValue is a List).

Comment: Thank you it is working. Yes it is a list of Beans. How to get here bean values. Ex element.getName() like this.

Comment: `${element.name}`. That's basic JSP EL stuff. Take some time to read documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine.